# Haskell: where is the "parse error in pattern"

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching, operator-precedence, parse-error

This is the code I have:

```
connected :: [(Integer,Integer)] -> Bool
connected [] = True
connected [(_,_)] = True
connected (a,b):(c,d):xs
                 | a > c     = False
                 |otherwise = connected (c,d):xs
```

When I load it GHCi it shows

> `error: parse error in pattern: connected`

Where did I make a mistake?

Comment: Minor style note: `foo | x = False | otherwise = something` is (IMO) more commonly written as `foo = not x && something`. In your case, you can use `connected (...) = a <= c && connected (...)`.

Answer (score 6):

You need to add parentheses around your cons expressions in two places:

```
connected :: [(Integer,Integer)] -> Bool
connected [] = True
connected [(_,_)] = True
connected ((a,b):(c,d):xs)                           -- (2)
                 | a > c     = False
                 | otherwise = connected ((c,d):xs)  -- (1)
```

1. Function application binds more tightly than infix operators, so `connected (c,d) : xs` gets parsed as `(connected (c,d)) : xs`.
2. A similar thing happens in the pattern expression. Although the unhelpful error message you get there is rather unfortunate.

Opinionated side note: I recommend always writing infix operators with spaces around them (for example, `a : b` instead of `a:b`), because I think omitting the whitespace subtly implies that the operator binds more tightly than it really does.